# Google SEO: Wrong typo suggestions

Tags: seo, google-search

My girlfriend is starting a new business which is not yet ready for the public (opening soon) but I'm already taking care of putting it on Google Maps and Google Search.

The business is named `Peace of Cake Studio` and it's already on Maps and Search if you search for it. The website is not yet available and won't show up on search results.

However, Google shows the following when searching for `Peace of Cake Studio`:

> Including results for ***piece*** of cake studio
>
> Search only for peace of cake studio

I know this is a common typo and owners of business with `piece` in the name will optimize for the `peace` typo. But is there anyway to optimize this on our side?

Comment: *But is there anyway to optimize this on our side?* No. You cannot stop it. The suggestion comes from a dictionary and/or thesaurus ontology which is set and only automatically updated using AI machine learning. The general exception? Branding. However, *peace* is not a brandable term and you have a long way to go to making your existing business name brand strong enough to be included into the brand ontology. Unless you are Pepsi, Conoco Phillips, Colt or Remington, a smaller brand cannot soak into the brand ontology easily if at all.

Comment: Thanks @closetnoc. Do you want to move that to an answer so I can accept it?